# How close are two Gaussian random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Given two Gaussian random variables A and B with (mean, standard deviation) of (a,s) and (b,m) respectively, is there a scalar w in [0,1] that indicates how close A and B are?

Comment: Instinctively, the answer depends on a closeness metric.  If I care about |x-y|, where x and y are draws, the resulting metric will be very different from if my metric is $(x-y)^2$

Comment: There are lots and lots of different [statistical distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance) and [divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)): metrics (or nonsymmetric generalizations thereof) on spaces of probability measures.  The field of *optimal transport* is largely focused on studying such distances.  So in short: yes.  But to get a more useful answer, you should maybe clarify why you want this and what you would use it for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the measure of the closeness of two distributions $p_A$ and $p_B$ You could use the [Bhattacharyya coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance)
$$w=\int \sqrt{p_A(x)p_B(x)}\,dx\in[0,1],$$
which for two Gaussian distributions (means $a,b$; variances $s^2$, $m^2$) is given by $w=e^{-d}$ with
$$d=\frac{1}{4} \ln \left [ \frac 1 4 \left( \frac{s^2}{m^2}+\frac{m^2}{s^2}+2\right ) \right ] +\frac{1}{4} \frac{(a-b)^{2}}{s^2+m^2}. $$

Comment: For help with interpretation see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296361/intuition-of-the-bhattacharya-coefficient-and-the-bhattacharya-distance/296604#374587

Comment: Alternate interpretation: Taking the square root converts both distributions into unit vectors in $L^2$, and then the inner product gives the cosine of the angle between these vectors.

Answer (score 4):

This depends really on the use you will have of that distance ... For many (statistical) purposes an asymmetric divergence is more natural than a symmetric distance. So look into the Kullback-Leibler divergence, for univariate normals see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7449/11887, for the multivariate case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Multivariate_normal_distributions.

For help with interpretations see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758

Answer (score 3):

The Kolmogorov distance is a possible answer. I derived it in [this article](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/EquivalenceExceedanceProbabilities.html) of my former blog (at the end of the article).